# ActionController::ParameterMissing in SignupsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, form-for

On submit my form throws error parameterMissing, I look at my routes and for creates is shows signups, also I tried using new_signup in the from both neither of these seem to fixed the error. I do not understand why this is not working, and search other post to figured it out but to no avail.

Full Error

ActionController::ParameterMissing in SignupsController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: signup

```
private
def signup_params
  params.require(:signup).permit(:email)
end
end
```

Server logs

```
 Started POST "/signups" for 50.17.182.190 at 2016-01-17 22:06:10 +0000
 Cannot render console from 50.17.182.190! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
 Processing by SignupsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"qteb42ekyyISXRfxX/aJEq6msi5nywvHb/vx0aTBkhLZ61hUutdgrRGP7QK6Jd2jxEesTBANQ9FiXGTLhX7crA=="}
 Completed 400 Bad Request in 70ms
  ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: signup):
  app/controllers/signups_controller.rb:18:in `signup_params'
  app/controllers/signups_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Here is my form

```
   <%= form_for(@signup, html: { class: 'form-inline' }) do |f| %>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="signups">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signups" placeholder="Enter  email">
          </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
   </form>
   <% end %>
```

Controller

```
 class SignupsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 @signup = Signup.new
 end

  def create
  @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)

  if @signup.save
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for expressing interest."
  else
  render action: 'new', alert: "Signup failed."
  end
  end

 private
 def signup_params
  params.require(:signup).permit(:email)
 end
 end
```

Routes

```
 root GET/  signups#new
             signups POST   /signups(.:format)             signups#create
          new_signup GET    /signups/new(.:format)         signups#new
             courses GET    /courses(.:format)             courses#index
                     POST   /courses(.:format)             courses#create
          new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)         courses#new
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the full text of the actual error message.

Comment: I was just posting it.

Comment: It looks like you are duplicating your `form` tags.  The Rails `form_for` creates a `form` tag for you, but you also have a manual `form` tag in the next line: `<form class="form-inline">`.  Remove this line, and the `</form>` as well, and this should fix your issue.
Also, always indent!  That would make it much easier to read your form.

Comment: I tried that does not fix the error.

Comment: ...see meagar's answer.  Also, this may help: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 2):

Your controller expects `params[:signups][:email]`, but your markup doesn't actually provide such a field for the `<form>` to submit.

You need to use the form helper being provided to you by `form_for` to produce your `<input>` tags, so that the *name* of each `input` matches the properties of the model you've given `form_for`.

In this case, your email `<input>` should be replaced with:

```
= f.text_field :email
```

This will produce an input with the correct name attribute: `name="signups[email]"`

Comment: This form is a bootstrap form- should I used something else instead.